# Mercurial doesn't ask for password in Apache

Tags: apache, mercurial, redmine

My apache config:

```
GNU nano 2.2.6       File: /etc/apache2/conf.d/hg.config                      

# Use PerlLoadModule Apache2::Redmine when using apache2, or else you might get$

PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
ScriptAliasMatch ^/repos/hg(.*) "/var/mercurial/hgwebdir.cgi$1"
#ScriptAlias /repos/hg  "/var/mercurial/hgwebdir.cgi"
<Location /repos/hg>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine Mercurial Repository"
    Require valid-user

    #Redmine auth
    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost"
    RedmineDbUser "redmine"
    RedmineDbPass "xxxxxx"
</Location>
```

When I enter `tracker.dev01/repos/hg` it asks for password, but when I enter `tracker.dev01/repos/hg/test` it shows me the repo without password.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out that the problem was that the project was PUBLIC, and I was forcing the logging in. Redmine.pm says that the script allows anonymous users to browse the repository for public projects, that's why I was getting 500 Internal Server Error.

So I removed the forcing logging withing  and let it set as  instead of using a regex, set the Project as PRIVATE and its now working!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be too simple... but comment suggests to use `Apache2::Redmine` and you use `Apache::Redmine`.  You are using apache2, do you?

Comment: Lol didnt look at that, gonna try. Thanks

Comment: ACtually it says a lot of RedmineDSN... redefined at..., don't know why, Googling it doesn't lead to anything (using keywords Redmine perl redefined). But I came up with the solution reading Redmine.pm by mistake!